# Code to retrieve images using requests doesn't work on python 3.7 but works on python 3.11

Tags: python, python-requests

I have this code that retrieves an image from a website and saves it to my local machine.

Minimum reproducible code:

```
import os
import requests


path = 'https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/images/1138/31-MINIDIP.jpg'
filename = 'images/image1.jpg'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.54'}

def retrieve():
    try:
        resp = requests.get(
            path,
            headers=headers)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            with open(filename, "wb") as f:
                f.write(resp.content)
        else:
            print('Failed to download image file. Status Code: ' + str(resp.status_code))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.mkdir('images')
    retrieve()
```

Output from 3.7: Failed to download image file. Status Code: 403

Output from 3.11: (No error. Image downloaded and saved inside the images folder)

If I run the code using python version 3.11, the code works fine without any issue. However, when i use python version 3.7, I get error 403. In both instances, I am using requests package version 2.31. Also, if i change the url to an image from a different website, the code for 3.7 also works. Any idea how I can fix this assuming using python 3.11 is not an option.

Additional Note:
I actually tried several other ways to download the image including using urllib, wget, and httpx. But all of them could not solve my error 403 issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Should the filename bit be in quotes?

Comment: This wouldn't have worked on Python 3.11. If it seemed to work, you were actually running different code.

Comment: I can view the URL in my browser, but when I use the Chrome dev tools to copy the network request as a curl command (so it should have all the same correct headers) the curl request fails with 403. So I think it's plausible that OP's request is somehow working in 3.11 and not 3.7 due to some subtle difference, but both sides of that are very mysterious.

Comment: Filenames should always be absolute paths if you want consistent results.

Comment: Edited the code to fix that. In my actual (longer and more complicated) code, I do some additional processing in order to get the filename and I did not want to include them in the snippet as I don't think they're relevant. So in my snippet i just wrote a generic filename and i just forgot the quotes. But rest assured, it should be a string.

Comment: Please make sure that you have a proper [mre] - that the code actually reflects what you are actually trying; that it doesn't work in 3.7 in the specific way that you describe; and that it **does** work in 3.11, **copied and pasted, without adding or changing anything**. Also check whether the result is sensitive to the image URL you are looking up. "In both instances, I am using requests package version 2.31" - *exactly how did you verify this*?

Comment: @user2357112, can you please explain why it wouldn't work on python 3.11? I'm pretty sure i'm using a 3.11 interpreter on Pycharm and I don't have any issues with the code when i run it. Thanks.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, In order to test this, I made two different projects in Pycharm. One using a 3.7 python interpreter and the other one using 3.11. Code contents were identical. I made sure that the package versions were the same on Pycharm by going to File-> Settings -> Project: <Project Name> -> Python Interpreter.

Comment: That **will not do the trick**. Every Python interpreter on the system has its **own set of installed third-party packages**, which would include Requests. So you would need to separately verify that the "Python Interpreter" chosen in each case has the same version of Requests installed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I see. Can you tell me how I can verify that? Or any links how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: @makki: It wouldn't have worked on Python 3.11 because you had invalid string syntax. We need to see something you *actually ran* that *actually reproduced the problem* when run (and that means running *exactly* the posted code on 3.7 and 3.11 and verifying the behavior).

Comment: @user2357112 just edited my post to reflect the minimum reproducible code

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code you provided:

1. The value of 'filename' is not a string. It should be enclosed in
   quotes.
2. Make sure the 'images' folder exists before running the code, or you'll get an error when trying to write the file.
3. If you're using Python 3.7, you might have an older version of the 'requests' library. Make sure to update this library to the latest version

Comment: Thanks for the response.
1. Like I mentioned in the comment on original post, I just forgot to enclose the filename in quotes because it was just a placeholder. 

2. Yup, i do have additional pre-processing to ensure that the paths and folders are valid. 

3. This is one of the things that I made sure when I did my testing. I am using Pycharm and in order to get the versions that I am using, I went to File-> Settings -> Project: <Project Name> -> Python Interpreter. I made sure that both version of the requests library are the same. i.e. 2.31.0

Answer (score 0):

After getting some help from someone outside StackOverflow, I finally managed to solve the issue. It looked like the website refuses to talk to clients that offer to negotiate older SSL/TLS versions. So in order to solve it, I was advised to update urllib3 to the latest version(currently 2.0.4) and subclass the HTTPAdapter to use at least TLS 1.2 protocol.

Final code now looks like this:

```
import os
import platform
import requests
import ssl


path = 'https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/images/1138/31-MINIDIP.jpg'
filename = 'images/image1.jpg'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/116.0.1938.54'}

class MyHTTPAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections,
            maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block,
            ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,
        )

def retrieve():
    sess = requests.Session()
    sess.mount("https://", MyHTTPAdapter())

    resp = sess.get(
        path,
        headers=headers)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        print('Successful request. Status Code: ' + str(resp.status_code))
        # print(requests.get('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check', verify=False).json()['tls_version'])
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(resp.content)
    else:
        print('Request failed. Status Code: ' + str(resp.status_code))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.mkdir('images')
    print('Python version: ' + platform.python_version())
    print('Python requests version: ' + requests.__version__)
    retrieve()
```